# KDE Desktop themes not installing?

Tags: themes, kde

I am currently trying out KDE plasma as it has far better customization. I tried to install the Unity Ambiance and Unity Radiance themes from the Desktop theme section in System Settings.

It says when you click Get New Themes that I have them both installed but in the Theme Tab neither one shows up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Testing with UnityAmbiance**

Trying from the KDE System Settings > Workspace Appearance > Desktop Theme > Get New Themes

Seems to have problems -> Looking the .xsession-errors. It is telling:

> plasmapkg(2824)/libplasma Plasma::Package::installPackage:  Package plugin name  "Unity Ambiance" contains invalid characters
>
> Installation of /tmp/kde-USER///159937-UnityAmbiance.tar.gz failed.
>
> systemsettings(2804)/knewstuff (api): Command failed

**Workaround**

1) Download the them from the http://kde-look.org/content/show.php/Unity+Ambiance?content=159937

2) Unpack it to the ~/.kde/share/apps/desktoptheme/

[image]

3) Inform the maker/developer